# Google Sheets sparkline, with importrange, with condition am I able to do this?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sparklines

So I have two google sheets books.    Book1 and Book2.

I currently have Book1 importing some info off Book2 to create a small sparkline graph.
It's pulling information from Book2 column A3 through G3 to create a small graph.

My current code is (in a Book1 cell)

```
=SPARKLINE(IMPORTRANGE("Book2","Sheet1!A3:G3"), 
{"charttype","bar";"max",100;"color1","Green";"color2","red"})
```

However, I'd like this sparkline and importrange only to work IF a condition on Book1 is met.

So in Book1 if a cell has a condition (example) TRUE, then the formula above (which is in another cell in Book1) would apply and it would go ahead and import from Book2 and create the graph in Book1.

I'm not sure how to make a condition on my formula.  I've tried IF statements without success.  Hoping somebody out there could teach me something today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(A1="abc", SPARKLINE(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1!A3:G3"), 
 {"charttype", "bar"; "max", 100; "color1", "green"; "color2", "red"}), )
```

if cell A1 contains `abc` do sparkline otherwise do nothing

Comment: Thank you so much for the formula!   I really appreciate it!    Excellent contribution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to achieve what you desire.

```js
function buildMyChart(){
  // Get the sheets from the spreadSheet attach to this script
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var book1Sheet = sheets[0];
  var book2Sheet = sheets[1];
  
  // Get values from your Book2
  var rangeParameter = "A3:G3";
  book2SheetRange = book2Sheet.getRange(rangeParameter);
  
  // If the cell has value "true", then insert the graph
  var cellConditionParameter = "A1";
  if(book1Sheet.getRange().getValues()[0][0]){
    
    var chart = book1Sheet.newChart()
      .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
      .addRange(book2SheetRange) // Range from Book2
      .setPosition(2, 2, 0, 0) // position where you want to put your chart 
      .build();
    book1Sheet.insertChart(chart);
    
  }
  
}
```

The code from above will get both sheets, take the range you desire from your Book2 and if the value in a specific cell is "True" in Book1, then it will insert the chart using the [***insertChart()***](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertchartchart) method.

### Notice

I am not using Sparkline as the type, because it will be soon deprecated, so instead I am using "LINE".  You can check all chart types [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/chart-type)

Comment: Thank you very much for the script! :)  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured something out that worked well.

`=SPARKLINE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url of other sheet","Sheet1!A1:Z100"), "Select Col24 where Col2='"&cell number within sheet in Book1  such as E5 or whatever&"'"), {"charttype","bar";"max",100;"color1","Green";"color2","green"})`

This really worked well for me. 
Thanks for all the input!!